# Android App To Programmatically Receive Incoming SMS Message and Reply Back With A Response

Tags: android, android-studio

I am hoping to receive some guidance with the issue described below, I am trying to understand if current version of Android OS will allow me to achieve the following:

Background:

I have developed an app and using a basic Android phone as the control panel to manage a peripheral devices connected to the phone / app by wifi and Bluetooth

I want to be able to periodically send an sms to the app / control panel and as the app will be the only app on the device and always running i want the app to:

1. Detect the incoming SMS
2. perform certain diagnostic / queries upon detecting the incoming sms
3. retrieve specific diagnostic values
4. reply back to the number that sent the sms with a custom message containing diagnostic information in point 3.

The Control panel itself displays a splash screen and is public facing.

Achieving points 2-3 above are not the issue.

I am needing for points 1 and 4 above , the receiving of the sms and replying back with a response to occur without there being any visual sign on the display itself the the above is occurring.

Its my understanding that the above functionality to programmatically receive and sms and send a reply was achievable in earlier version of android.

I am told that at some point later version were modified to prevent the above from being possible to perform programatically.

Thanks in advance for any advise provided

Answer (score -1):

Sending SMS is big Task.
Only default SMS app can send the SMS in android.
To set the app as default messaging app we need to get the sms send and receive permission and register as messaging app in google play store (if you are planning to release it to play store or already released)
In short you have to build the full-fledged Messaging app to send sms.

Comment: Once the fully fledged messaging functionality is integrated into the existing app will it be possible to have the active app receive and then reply to received sms's programmatically so that the sms activity occurs without it being visible on the splash screen of the  control panel.

By the way the solution will be installed as a dedicated app on a android phone aka kiosk mode so it want be an app that will appear on play store for download the app will be pre installed on the phone which will operate as the control panel for the connected peripheral devices .

I appreciate your time

Comment: Yes, Once you implement sms app functionality and user set it as default sms app. Your app will get full access to all the messages. You can receive and disable/trigger the notification.

Comment: This is incorrect. Sending SMS can almost be a one-liner. It can be done by any app which has SEND_SMS permission, not just default SMS app. Finally, if you want user to choose your app as default SMS app, you don't ask for two particular permissions, but rather a role.

Comment: Hi @BudimirGrom any random app can't get send SMS permission, only default SMS and few other whitelisted apps (like payments, bank apps) can get. About your second statement, once you ask you default SMS app, your app will get all these permissions automatically and you can't ask for default SMS app without mentioning permissions and broadcasts receivers in app manifest.